# Is there a 'lighter' method of solving this custom AnimationRunnable?

Tags: android

I've been working on this problem for a couple days now and have been unable to solve the problem.

I have a number of animations all implemented as Runnables that will run continually while the user uses the application. There are 4 different animations spanning from logo_animation000 to 115 and z_animation000 to 515:

- ConnectingAnimation (Running while the application is connecting to a device)
- ConnectingCompleteAnimation (Run once when the connection is complete)
- TransitiontoSleepingAnimation(Run once when the state of the application changes)
- SleepingAnimation(Run while the state of the application is : "Sleeping"

These animations are too big to work by using the regular animation-list and as such I was forced to use my own implementation. I "solved" this problem with the following class :

```
    abstract class MyAnimationRunnable implements Runnable {
        protected final int interval;
        protected final String pattern;
        protected final OptimisedImageView view;
        protected long firstFrameAt;
        protected int current;
        protected Drawable drawable;
        protected int frameCounter = 0;

        public MyAnimationRunnable(int interval, int firstFrame, String pattern, OptimisedImageView view) {
            this.interval = interval;
            this.pattern = pattern;
            this.view = view;
            this.current = firstFrame;
            this.firstFrameAt = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            handler.post(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String name = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, pattern, current);
            final int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
            if (id != 0) {
                final Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
                view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
            current++;
            if (runAgain()) {
                frameCounter++;
                long nextAt = firstFrameAt + (frameCounter * interval);
                long delay = nextAt - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 1;
                if (delay > 0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                } else {
                    this.run();
                }
            }
        }

        protected abstract boolean runAgain();
    };

   private void startSleepingAnimation() 
    {

        zzzAnimation = new MyAnimationRunnable(50, 1, "z_animation%04d", zzzImageView) {
            @Override
            protected boolean runAgain() {
                if (current == 510) {
                    current = 470; // this seems to fit into the infinite loop.
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    private void startConnectingAnimation() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(connectingCompleteAnimation);
        handler.removeCallbacks(zzzAnimation);
        handler.removeCallbacks(transitionToSleepingAnimation);
        connectingResourceCount = 1;
        zzzImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        connectingAnimation = new MyAnimationRunnable(50, connectingResourceCount, "logo_animation%04d", babyImageView) {
            @Override
            protected boolean runAgain() {
                if (current == 30) {
                    current = 1;
                }
                connectingResourceCount = current;
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    // The remaining two animations have been left out since this oughta be sufficient for understanding the code.
```

This works alright on my Samsung Galaxy S3. However on older phones this causes a crash after 20-30 seconds. Any ideas on how I can make this code lighter and more efficient?

Comment: Please post the logcat stack trace.

Comment: Maybe delay is always <= 0 causing infinite recursive calls to run() on slower devices.. causing the garbage collector to not clean up the spend ressorces, just a thought.

Comment: Interesting. This could possibly explain some of the behaviour of the app on the Sony Xperia I was testing on. Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to solve this problem ?

Comment: With what exception does the app crash on older phones?